# sepa_debit payemnt method with stripe subscriptopn doesn't work

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe with react-native and I want to integrate PaymentIntent with Subscription as described in this [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview)

the issue is I can't show the `SEPA` as a valid payment option at the front-end.
Stripe mentioned in their [subscription API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-payment_settings) that you can pass the `payment_method_types` as you do in `payment_intent`. however, it seems like it doesn't work!

let me explain with examples

- first scenario using the regular payment_intent

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: 1099,
    currency: 'EUR',
    customer: customer.id,
    payment_method_types: ["card", "sepa_debit"]
  });

  return res.json({
    // @ts-ignore
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
    customer: customer.id,
  });
```

and the result would be like as you can see the SEPA option is showing
[image]

- second scenario when I'm using the subscription

```js
  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [{
      price: "price_1JwZ4tJyYehXW8ayueOKGDUM",
    }],
    payment_settings: {
      payment_method_types: ["card", "sepa_debit"]
    },
    payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
  });

  return res.json({
    // @ts-ignore
    paymentIntent: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret,
    ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
    customer: customer.id,
  });
```

the result would be like (no SEPA option)

[image]

any idea why `sepa_debit` working with payment_intent and not with subscription?

Comment: Have you tried other payment method types?

Comment: nop! because I'm interested only in card and sepa_debit  @CebrailYilmaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Payment Intent that is generated during Subscription creation automatically sets `setup_future_usage: off_session` to ensure that the saved Payment Method can be used for off-sessions recurring payments in the future.

Looking at the code for Stripe's React Native SDK it looks like it relies on logic found in the Android and iOS to determine when to show `sepa_debit` as an option in the Payment Sheet. Both these SDKs do not currently support `sepa_debit` for a Payment Intent with `setup_future_usage` set, which explains why you're not seeing it show up as an option for your Subscription Payment Intent. You can see the code I referenced here:

- [Android](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/a17300e0caf9f81a577f178fe78f0dc954e5a0f7/paymentsheet/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/paymentsheet/forms/SepaDebitSpec.kt#L21)
- [iOS](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/00fe1bc3b6abedd7b3a08776ac121d07289cd560/Stripe/PaymentSheet%2BPaymentMethodAvailability.swift#L45)